# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have double foreach here. Here is my view

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Klasifikasi</th>
            <th>Lokasi</th>
            <th>Cp_Or</th>
            <th>Tahun</th>
            <th>ID_Master_Buku</th  
            <th>Jenis</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Tgl_Masuk</th>
            <th>can_issue</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Edisi</th>
            <th>Pengarang</th>
            <th>Deskripsi</th>
            <th>Penerbit</th>
            <th>Judul</th>
            <th>Jumlah_Buku</th>
            <th>Bahasa</th>
            <th>Gambar</th>
            <th>Subjek</th>
            <th>Topik</th>
    </tr>


    @foreach($bukus as $buku)
    @foreach($buku->tmbuku as $item)
    <tr>
            <td>{{$buku->ID}}</td>      
            <td>{{$buku->ISBN}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Klasifikasi}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Lokasi}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Cp_Or}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Tahun}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->ID_Master_Buku}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Jenis}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Status}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->Tgl_Masuk}}</td>
            <td>{{$buku->can_issue}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->ID}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Edisi}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Pengarang}}</td>       
            <td>{{$item->Deskripsi}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Penerbit}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Judul}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Jumlah_Buku}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Bahasa}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Gambar}}</td>      
            <td>{{$item->Subjek}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->Topik}}</td>
            @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach </table>
```

It works in my other views. But here, I got an error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add output of dd($buku) after first foreach.

Comment: This is my first model

Comment: I think you  didn't understand what I've mentioned. Change your code to this for seeing output:   @foreach($bukus as $buku) {{ dd($buku) }}
    @foreach($buku->tmbuku as $item)  and paste it in your question.

Comment: check if you passed the data from the controler with the corect name

Comment: @motto, im sorry, its misspell. i know what you mean, but i think I have a new error, I update my question with title 
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel and change"

Comment: hope you want to see it, guys

Comment: Please provide your controller too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like at least one `$buku->tmbuku` is `null`...

Try wrapping it in an `@if`:

```
@foreach($bukus as $buku)
    @if($tmbuku = $buku->tmbuku
        @foreach($tmbuku as $item)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$buku->ID}}</td>      
        <td>{{$buku->ISBN}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Klasifikasi}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Lokasi}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Cp_Or}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Tahun}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->ID_Master_Buku}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Jenis}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Status}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->Tgl_Masuk}}</td>
        <td>{{$buku->can_issue}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->ID}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Edisi}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Pengarang}}</td>       
        <td>{{$item->Deskripsi}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Penerbit}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Judul}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Jumlah_Buku}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Bahasa}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Gambar}}</td>      
        <td>{{$item->Subjek}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->Topik}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if its null and items count before executing the second loop e.g.:

```
@foreach($bukus as $buku)
@if(!is_null( $buku->tmbuku ) && count( $buku->tmbuku ) )
    @foreach($buku->tmbuku as $item)
    <tr>
       <td>{{$buku->ID}}</td>      
       <td>{{$buku->ISBN}}</td>
       <td>{{$buku->Klasifikasi}}</td>....
       <td>{{$item->ID}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->Edisi}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->Pengarang}}</td>       
       <td>{{$item->Deskripsi}}</td>...
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

@endforeach